# Cannot set property innerHTML error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to automate the process of opening an external site from a button of an internal site that I created, but I can not reference the document I created, follow the code below, tried several times and could not, any help is valid, thank you so much.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Principal</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\JQuery\jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\jQueryMask\dist\jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
  <script src="\\fswcorp\ceic\ssoa\gaacc\System\jQueryUI\jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#dateBegin").mask('00/00/0000');
      $("#dateEnd").mask('00/00/0000');

      $("#buttonDownloadBRScan").click(function() {
        $windowopen = window.open();
        $windowopen.location.href = "https://www.fdibr.com.br/autenticacao/autenticacao/login";
        $test = $windowopen.document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = "7478704";
      })
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="dataInput">
    <label id="labelDateBegin">Data Inicial</label>
    <input id="dateBegin" type="date" />
    <label id="labelDateEnd">Data Final</label>
    <input id="dateEnd" type="date" />
  </div>
  <br><br>
  <button id="buttonDownload">Download</button>
  <button id="buttonDownloadBRScan">Download BRScan</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You need CORS access to use JavaScript on the external page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have access to that domain in the window you're opening (same origin policy), you have to wait for the window to finish opening first before accessing elements inside.

```
$("#buttonDownloadBRScan").click(function(){
  const w = window.open('https://www.fdibr.com.br/autenticacao/autenticacao/login');
  w.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    w.document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = "7478704";
  });
})
```

Comment: Actually I think it should be: `w.document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML = PhishingHtml` :]

Comment: I realized your idea, however I can not input the information in the user element that is on the other page, it loads the page, but does not assign the value in the element. = /

Comment: @FelipeDiasdeSouza Do you have access to the domain in the other window? If not, then it's impossible due to security issues.

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes i have access in domain, but i can not input information in the element(input) that is on the page: "https://www.fdibr.com.br/autenticacao/autenticacao/login"

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<input id="yourID" type="button" onclick="open_page()" value="Your Message Here"/>

<script>

    function open_page () {
        window.open('Your Webpage');
}

</script>
```

Comment: I realized your idea, however I can not input the information in the user element that is on the other page, it loads the page, but does not assign the value in the element. = /

Answer (score 0):

the external site and your internal site have different domain,you can't modify the external site content from your internal site directly.you can use window.postMessage,maybe it would resolve your problem